# Transforming list with key-values into Excel with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

If I have this structure:

```
 [{'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 16, 'email': 'paul@gmail.com', 'data': [{'name_dependent': 'George', 'email': 'george@gmail.com', 'supporterId': 16},{'name_dependent': 'Ana', 'email': 'ana@gmail.com', 'supporterId': 2}]}]
```

How can I export it to excel selecting only the keys I want to turn into columns? For example I want only name,email,name dependent and email to be in my excel with its values...

Comment: The structure is broken

Comment: Oh okay i just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can start with pd.json_normalize() and follow it up with some custom made columns.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data).explode('data')
df['name_dependent'] = df['data'].map(lambda x: x['name_dependent'])
df['email'] = df['data'].map(lambda x: x['email'])
```

Outputting:

```
   name  supporterId             email name_dependent
0  Paul           16  george@gmail.com         George
0  Paul           16     ana@gmail.com            Ana
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d = [["name1", 21, "1@gmail.com"],
     ["name2", 22, "2@gmail.com"], 
     ["name3", 23, "3@gmail.com"]
    ]
rows = [i for i in range(len(d[0]))]
cols = ["name", "id", "email"]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, rows, cols)
```

**cols** is your keys

**Output :**

```
    name  id   email

0  name1  21  1@gmail.com
1  name2  22  2@gmail.com
2  name3  23  3@gmail.com
```